# How can I tell if no_root_squash is enabled from an NFS client without mounting the share?

Tags: centos, nfs

Obviously, I can look at `/etc/exports` on the NFS server-side to see if `no_root_squash` is enabled, but is there a way I can check this from the NFS client-side without actually mounting the share?

Running `showmount -e myserver` and `rpcinfo -p myserver` from the NFS client don't help.

I'm using CentOS 6.